# Custom acl resource for api endpoint

Tags: acl, webapi, magento2.4.4

I have a route defined in one of my modules like this

```
<route url="/V1/some/path/:type" method="GET">
    <service class="SomeClassOrInterfaceHere" method="getType"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="????" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

What this basically says is that for the endpoint `/V1/some/path/:type` (which contains a parameter `type`) the method `getType` from the class (or preference for the interface) `SomeClassOrInterfaceHere` is called. This works nicely, but I may need to allow or not allow access on this url to an admin depending on the value of the `type` parameter.
`type` can in theory be anything so creating one endpoint and one acl resource for each type is not an option. Is there something I can put in the `resource` section (or any other ideas) to be able to control at application level the access to this endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to use whildcards or additional access validation classes so I went with this approach.

I placed in the resource tag  `<resource ref="???" />` a general resource name that is the root of all my other ACL resources for the module. Basically if you have access to any of the module's ACL, you have access to this general resource.

And I added a plugin for my `SomeClassOrInterfaceHere` only in `webapi_rest/di.xml` where I check the validity of the `$type` parameter.
If it's valid, I proceed with the regular response. Otherwise I throw `n` Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthorizationException` exception

```
public function beforeGetTypes(SomeClassOrInterfaceHere $subject, string $type)
{
    $isAllowed = 'Custom logic here that returns true or false'($type);
    return $isAllowed ? null : throw new AuthorizationException(
        __("The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.", "This {$type}")
    ); 
}
```

this is not pretty because the endpoint is still reached but nothing gets executed if I'm not supposed to have access.